# Does anyone know what this soil insect is?

Tags: identification, bugs

I bought a palm plant from Aldi a few weeks ago but only just notice some critters hanging around in the soil. Only spotted a couple so not riddled with them (yet).

Just wondered if they're harmful and if they are what is best to get rid of them?

They look like small spiders and they can jump if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its a jumping spider, but what sort?

Comment: It has eight legs, and insects have six. It appears to be a spider.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet. It could be a zebra spider. I've heard of spider mites (if they even are spiders) being a problem, but you don't tend to hear about larger spiders like this being a problem for plants. I wouldn't worry about them myself.

Comment: Jumping spiders are carnivorous, so they won't hurt your plant. It's possible that the plant you purchased contained eggs, which have now hatched. They appear to like living outside rather than indoors, so if you could put your plant outside for a couple of days you may be able to let them disperse naturally. Here's more information: https://www.pestworld.org/pest-guide/spiders/jumping-spiders/

Answer (score 2):

I hybridize daylilies in zone 4.  When collecting seed pods this time of year I always find some of these guys hiding out in the pods. Quite sure they dine on other insects who come into pods. Harmless.